# display a NSString in cell.accessoryView instead of a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, accessoryview

How can I assign a string as the accessory view of a cell instead of a `UIImageView`?

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A string is not a view. Perhaps you want to display a `UILabel`?

The `accessoryView` property is a `UIView`, so you can assign any `UIView` subclass to it.

`cell.accessoryView = myLabel` will work just fine.